# Second col moves whole content up and makes some of the content invisible

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

When I try to preview my page on mobile devices the second col on the right is moved under the first col as it should be. The problem is that the whole content on my site is moved/pushed up and text (TAXI) is not visible.

[PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY0L7.jpg)

On phone it looks like this
[PHONE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7oOu.png)

Here is code of the columns. What can I do for fixing it?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <section id="mainpage">
      <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center info">
        <div class="row mb-5">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 my-auto">
            <h1 class="text-uppercase text-white">TAXI VÍTKOV</h1>
            <h6 class="text-white lead text-uppercase">Potřebujete svést? Zavolejte.</h6>
            <h1 class="phone-number">777 996 166</h1>
            <p class="text-white">Potřebujete se rychle a pohodlně dostat z bodu A do bodu B? Překvapil Vás déšť, sníh nebo jiná komplikace? Odvezeme Vás kamkoliv, kdykoliv. Bezpečně a spolehlivě.
            </p>
          </div>

          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <div class="card-deck mb-3">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <div class="card-header  text-center">
                  <h4>Jízda již za</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="card-body">
                  <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">30kč/km</h1>

                  <table>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Čekání na zákazníka</td>
                        <td>4kč/min</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Znečištění vozidla</td>
                        <td>**kč</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

```
* {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: #fff;
      font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    }
    
    html {
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
    
    #top-page .top-page-image {
      background: url("https://patrikderka.cz/taxi_vitkov/doplnky/images/menu-top.jpg");
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 20px;
    }
    
    #bottom-page .bottom-page-image {
      background: url("https://patrikderka.cz/taxi_vitkov/doplnky/images/bottom-photo.png");
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 20px;
    }
    
    #mainpage {
      height: 100vh;
      min-height: 500px;
      background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)), url("https://patrikderka.cz/taxi_vitkov/doplnky/images/banner.jpg");
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    #mainpage .info {
      height: 100%;
    }
    #mainpage .info h1 {
      color: #f9d700;
      font-size: 60px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    #mainpage .card-header {
      background-color: #f9d700;
    }
    #mainpage .card-body {
      background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95)), url("https://patrikderka.cz/taxi_vitkov/doplnky/images/taxi-pattern.jpg");
      background-repeat: repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      color: #fff;
    }
    #mainpage .card-body h1 {
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    #mainpage .card-body table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

So I tried to make it in different way. Using vh-100.
Problem is, that it leaves me a big white space on the bottom of the page.
[space on the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUbS4.png)
code

```
<section id="top-page">
    <div class="top-page-image">
    </div>
</section>


<section id="mainpage">
    <header class="masthead">
        <div class="container info h-100">
          <div class="row h-100 align-items-center">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                <h1 class="text-uppercase text-white">TAXI VÍTKOV</h1>
                <h6 class="text-white lead text-uppercase">Potřebujete svést? Zavolejte.</h6>
                <h1 class="phone-number">777 996 166</h1>
                <p class="text-white">Potřebujete se rychle a pohodlně dostat z bodu A do bodu B? Překvapil Vás déšť, sníh nebo jiná komplikace?
                    Odvezeme Vás kamkoliv, kdykoliv. Bezpečně a spolehlivě.
                </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 price d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="card-deck mb-3">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                  <div class="card-header  text-center">
                    <h4>Jízda již za</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">30kč/km</h1>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        <td>Čekání na zákazníka</td>
                        <td>4kč/min</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>Znečištění vozidla</td>
                        <td>**kč</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
</section>
```

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#top-page .top-page-image {
  background: url("https://patrikderka.cz/taxi_vitkov/doplnky/images/menu-top.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 20px;
}

#bottom-page .bottom-page-image {
  background: url("https://patrikderka.cz/taxi_vitkov/doplnky/images/bottom-photo.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 20px;
}

#mainpage .masthead {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)), url("https://patrikderka.cz/taxi_vitkov/doplnky/images/banner.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#mainpage .info h1 {
  color: #f9d700;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#mainpage .card-header {
  background-color: #f9d700;
}
#mainpage .card-body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95)), url("https://patrikderka.cz/taxi_vitkov/doplnky/images/taxi-pattern.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  color: #fff;
}
#mainpage .card-body h1 {
  font-weight: 500;
}
#mainpage .card-body table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}/*# sourceMappingURL=styles_taxi.css.map */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the **@media** Rule in the CSS part. The @media rule is used in media queries to apply different styles for different media types/devices. This will help you to get rid of this and any query regarding different devices.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to use the @media rule for div class info, honestly, I was trying some position: and height:. Nothing worked for me. What you suggest trying?

Comment: Right now I tried to put padding-top in @media for .info. It fixes the problem with hidden text but it will make another problem. It hides text on the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with `@media rule height: auto;`.